# How do i cast from std::vector<DerivedClass*> to std::vector<BaseClass*>?

Tags: c++, casting

The code below shows what i want to do:

```cpp
Member variable:
std::vector<DerivedClass*> myPointers;

Function:
std::vector<BaseClass*> GetMyPointers()
{
  return SOMETHING_CAST<BaseClass*>(myPointers);
}
```

Comment: There is no cast.  A `std::vector<T*>` and `std::vector<U*>` are different types.  What high-level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `return { myPointers.begin(), myPointers.end() };`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such cast operator as even if A inherit from B, there is no reason for `std::vector<A>` to inherit of `std::vector<B>`.

The proposition of @songyuanyoa is to return a new `std::vector<BaseClass*>`. This idea is that individually each `Derived *` can be implicitly cast to `BaseClass *`.

So `return { myPointers.begin(), myPointers.end() };` builds a new vector in which each element is created from the same index element from the original vector. somehow equivalent to (but is smarter because uses the range constructor see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector<BaseClasse*> baseV;
for (auto p : myPointers)
   baseV.push_back(p); // implicit cast from derived to base
return baseV;
```